# Overflow issue with recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have some java code to color all regions of a map without any adjacent regions being colored the same color. However, I am running into a overflow error I cannot seem to resolve. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Guthrie{

    static int[][] adjMat;
    static char[] color;
    static int regions;

/**main method that initiates the rest of the program
Pre-Cond: user enters valid inputs when prompted
Post-Cond: print of all regions and colors
responses: error terminate
@return void*/
    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the following.");
        System.out.println("Filename to read?: ");
        String fileName = kbd.next();
        System.out.println("Number of regions?: ");
        regions = kbd.nextInt();
        adjMat = new int[regions][regions];
        color = new char[regions];
        reader(fileName);
            for(int i=0; i<regions; i++){
                color[i] = 'f';
            }
        if(colorReg(0)){
            for(int i=0; i<regions; i++){
                if(color[i] == 'r') System.out.println("Region " + i + " is red.");
                else if(color[i] == 'o') System.out.println("Region " + i + " is orange.");
                else if(color[i] == 'y') System.out.println("Region " + i + " is yellow.");
                else if(color[i] == 'g') System.out.println("Region " + i + " is green.");
            }
        }
        else System.out.println("Incompatible Map.");
        kbd.close();    
    }

    /**reads a user supplied file
    Pre-Cond: fileName is a valid String with a file by that String's name present
    Post-Cond: none
    responses: FileNotFoundException
    @param fileName - A user supplied String for a file name
    @return void*/
    public static void reader(String fileName)throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
        for(int i=0; i<regions; i++){
            String row=sc.nextLine();
            String[] splits=row.split(" ");
            for(int j=0; j<regions; j++){
                splits[j] = splits[j].trim();
            }
                for(int j = 0; j<regions; j++){
                adjMat[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(splits[j]);
            }           
        }
        sc.close();
    }

    /**checks if any adjacent regions are the same color as v
    Pre-Cond: v < regions and a valid integer
    Post-Cond: boolean true or false
    responses: error terminate
    @param v - region number
    @return boolean*/
    public static boolean checkColor(int v){
        for(int i=0; i<regions; i++){
            if(adjMat[v][i] == 1){
                if(color[v] == color[i]) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**recursively backtracks to color map without adjacent regions having the same color
    Pre-Cond: v < regions and a valid integer
    Post-Cond: boolean true or false
    responses: error terminate
    @param v - region number
    @return boolean*/
    public static boolean colorReg(int v){
        if(filled()) return true;
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            switch(i){
                case 0:{
                    color[v] = 'r';
                    if(checkColor(v)) break;
                }
                case 1:{
                    color[v] = 'o';
                    if(checkColor(v)) break;
                }
                case 2:{
                    color[v] = 'y';
                    if(checkColor(v)) break;
                }
                case 3:{
                    color[v] = 'g';
                    if(checkColor(v)) break;
                }

            }
        }
        if (colorReg(v++)) return true;
        v--;
        color[v] = 'f';
        return false;
    }

    /**checks if every region has been colored
    Pre-Cond: none
    Post-Cond: boolean true or false
    responses: error terminate
    @return boolean*/
    public static boolean filled(){
        for(int i=0; i<regions; i++){
            if(color[i] == 'f') return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `colorReg()` method calls itself:

```
if (colorReg(v++)) return true;
```

This will pass the same `v` value to the subsequent recursive call because you use the postfix increment, and will work with the same region. And will not progress with the regions but stuck with the initial `v=0` until you run into `StackOverflowError`!

Change it to prefix increment:

```
if (colorReg(++v)) return true;
v--;
```

Or explicit `+1` in which case you don't need to decrease it after:

```
if (colorReg(v + 1)) return true;
// No need v--
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Some of these issues stump me sometimes, I have a hard time thinking with recursion. Now I just need to fix the output printing :)

Comment: Do you happen to what would be causing my program to now be saying all the regions are colored as green? I'm guessing it might have to do with the loop but thought the break would fix that.

Comment: @SethNelson The `break` statements in the `if`s inside the `switch`: they will only break from the `switch` and not the enclosing `for`. If you want to break out from the `for`, use labels. Put a label before the `for`, e.g. `cycle:` and use `break cycle;`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're passing the same value of `v` down to every recursive call of `colorReg()` because you're using the postfix increment operator.

Instead of

```
if (colorReg(v++)) return true;
    v--;
```

try

```
if (colorRef(v+1)) return true;
```